# Join a collection of strings until character limit is reached

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, strings

### Question

I wrote a function which will take a collection of strings — and return a comma-separated string which doesn't exceed the specified character limit.

It essentially works by joining the collection of strings over and over again, and removing the last item in the collection each time, until the comma-separated string doesn't exceed the specified character limit.

```
private static string Join(IEnumerable<string> collection, int characterLimit)
{
    var values = new List<string>(collection);
    var joined = string.Join(", ", values);
    while (joined.Length > characterLimit)
    {
        values.RemoveAt(values.Count - 1);
        joined = string.Join(", ", values);
    }
    return joined;
}
```

I feel like there *must* more efficient way of doing this ... and that's what I'd **love** some help with.

---

### Example

```
private string[] words =
{
    "able", "acid", "angry", "automatic", "awake", "bad", "beautiful", "bent", "bitter",
    "black", "blue", "boiling", "bright", "broken", "brown", "certain", "cheap", "chemical", "chief", "clean",
    "clear", "cold", "common", "complete", "complex", "conscious", "cruel", "cut", "dark", "dead", "dear",
    "deep", "delicate", "dependent", "different", "dirty", "dry", "early", "elastic", "electric", "equal",
    "false", "fat", "feeble", "female", "fertile", "first", "fixed", "flat", "foolish", "free", "frequent",
    "full", "future", "general", "good", "gray", "great", "green", "hanging", "happy", "hard", "healthy", "high",
    "hollow", "ill", "important", "kind", "last", "late", "left", "like", "living", "long", "loose", "loud",
    "low", "male", "married", "material", "medical", "military", "mixed", "narrow", "natural", "necessary",
    "new", "normal", "old", "open", "opposite", "parallel", "past", "physical", "political", "poor", "possible",
    "present", "private", "probable", "public", "quick", "quiet", "ready", "red", "regular", "responsible",
    "right", "rough", "round", "sad", "safe", "same", "second", "secret", "separate", "serious", "sharp",
    "short", "shut", "simple", "slow", "small", "smooth", "soft", "solid", "special", "sticky", "stiff",
    "straight", "strange", "strong", "sudden", "sweet", "tall", "thick", "thin", "tight", "tired", "true",
    "violent", "waiting", "warm", "wet", "white", "wide", "wise", "wrong", "yellow", "young"
};

private void joinButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var characterLimit = 500; // the joined string's length will be <= 500
    var joined = Join(words, characterLimit); // the joined string
    Console.WriteLine("joined: " + joined);
    Console.WriteLine("joined.Length: " + joined.Length);
}
```

#### Output

```
joined: able, acid, angry, automatic, awake, bad, beautiful, bent, bitter, black, blue, boiling, bright, broken, brown, certain, cheap, chemical, chief, clean, clear, cold, common, complete, complex, conscious, cruel, cut, dark, dead, dear, deep, delicate, dependent, different, dirty, dry, early, elastic, electric, equal, false, fat, feeble, female, fertile, first, fixed, flat, foolish, free, frequent, full, future, general, good, gray, great, green, hanging, happy, hard, healthy, high, hollow, ill
joined.Length: 495
```

Comment: Yes that is inefficient

Comment: @Paparazzi That is precisely why I came to Code Review. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Heslacher already suggested you should start by first getting only as many words as you need and you can express the same algorithm with two different LINQ expressions by making it even easier to understand.

Additionaly you should name the parameters appropriately. The upper limit is exclusive so add this to its name.

## LINQ query syntax

The first alternative uses the query syntax:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> JoinableValues(this IEnumerable<string> values, int separatorLength, int maxLengthExclusive)
{
    var currentLength = 0;
    return 
        from x in values
        where (currentLength += x.Length + separatorLength) < maxLengthExclusive
        select x;
}
```

The other method then just consumes the result.

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator, int maxLengthExclusive)
{
    return string.Join(separator, values.JoinableValues(separator.Length, maxLengthExclusive));
}
```

Usually you would make only the `Join` `public` becasue the other one is just its helper.

There is still place for improvment and with C# 7 local functions you can encapsulate even the last part of it:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> JoinableValues(this IEnumerable<string> values, int separatorLength, int maxLengthExclusive)
{
    var currentLength = 0;

    return
        from x in values
        where IsJoinable(x)
        select x;

    bool IsJoinable(string value) => (currentLength += value.Length + separatorLength) < maxLengthExclusive;
}
```

---

## LINQ with extensions

The second alternative can be implemented with `TakeWhile`which agian, uses the same algorithm.

```
var maxLengthExclusive = 100;
var currentLength = 0;
var separator = ", ";
var joinableWords = words.TakeWhile(w => (currentLength += w.Length + separator.Length) < maxLengthExclusive);
```

The same as above encapsulated and with the new helper fuction:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> JoinableValues(this IEnumerable<string> values, int separatorLength, int maxLengthExclusive)
{
    var currentLength = 0;

    return values.TakeWhile(IsJoinable);

    bool IsJoinable(string value) => (currentLength += value.Length + separatorLength) < maxLengthExclusive;
}
```

Comment: I thought extension methods had to be public.  Is private a C# 7.0 feature?

Comment: @RickDavin they have to be static and the class has to be static too but they can have any access modifier you need them to have. It's not C# 7 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Although @TopinFrassi's solution is death plain and simple, I would separate the fetching of the values which fit in the limit and the actual joining with the separator like so

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FetchInRange(IEnumerable<string> collection, int characterLimit, int separationLength)
{

    int currentlength = -separationLength;

    foreach (var value in collection)
    {
        int length = value.Length + separationLength;
        currentlength += length;
        if (currentlength  > characterLimit)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        yield return value;
    }

}
private static string Join(IEnumerable<string> collection, int characterLimit, string separator = ", ")
{
    return string.Join(separator, FetchInRange(collection, characterLimit, separator.Length));
}
```

Each method has only one responsibility and they can be used for a wider range of separators as well.

Comment: I really like this answer but you are low key on some improvements it has over original.  For one, yours is more flexible since 'separator' is now an argument instead of hardcoded at ", ".  Plus your method eliminates 2 variables:  the 'values' list of string, as well  'joined'.  The OP seems to be a newbie (no offense intended) so bringing up these points helps teach him.

Comment: mover currentlength += length; and use it in the if

Comment: @Paparazzi good idea. fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like you're doing a *lot* of work for a quite simple problem.

Using `String.Join` is kind of an expensive operation and you call it a lot. Plus, you don't really need to remove values from your "original" list.

Let's try and "translate" your problem into simple lines of code.

> I wrote a function which will take a collection of strings — and
>   return a comma-separated string which doesn't exceed the specified
>   character limit.

Let's try to write code that fits *exactly* that sentence, and see how it goes.

```
private static string Join(IEnumerable<string> collection, int characterLimit)
{
    //Takes the collection of strings
    var joined = string.Join(", ", collection.ToArray());
    //Returns a comma-separated string
    joined = joined.Substring(0,characterLimit);
    //Trim the remaining characters
    joined = joined.Substring(0, joined.LastIndexOf(','));

    return joined;
}
```

This way, there's no loop and we join the strings only once.

The problem with your code is that it's, as you said, not the most efficient way to do what you want. When you write code, always  try to be conscious of the "cost" of the methods you use, and the amount of loops you use. Though I guess it comes with experience!

Lastly, I don't think `Join` is a good method name, considering the method doesn't *only* join strings. It's kind of hard for me to come up with a better name considering I don't have the context of your application. But you should try to find something more representative!

Comment: You missed one edge case. Assume that excatly at the `characterLimit` a word ends, then your solution will cut the last word. By changing the first `Subtring()` to `joined = joined.Substring(0, characterLimit + 1);` and adding an `if` before the second `Substring()` like `if (joined[characterLimit] == ',') { return joined.TrimEnd(','); }` will fix that issue.

Comment: There is no need to call `ToArray()` on the passed collection. `String.Join()` has an overload which takes an `IEnumerable<string>` as well.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it will crash if the character limit is less then the length of the first word.

Answer (score 1):

Not much to say about the current code.  It is clean enough but very inefficient.  Under the covers Join uses StringBuilder.

```
private static string Join(IEnumerable<string> collection, int characterLimit)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(characterLimit);
    foreach(string s in collection)
    {
        if (sb.Length + 2 + s.Length > characterLimit)
            break;
        if (sb.Length > 0)
            sb.Append(", ");
        sb.Append(s);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
    //var values = new List<string>(collection);
    //var joined = string.Join(", ", values);
    //while (joined.Length > characterLimit)
    //{
    //    values.RemoveAt(values.Count - 1);
    //    joined = string.Join(", ", values);
    //}
    //return joined;
}
```